# Use custom artemis.profile with ApacheMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Can I pass my custom `artemis.profile` to my ActiveMQ Artemis broker (the profile then points to the required location for `jolokia-access.xml`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *direct* support for using a custom `artemis.profile`, but you can modify the `bin/artemis` script. Here are the relevant lines:

```
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC='/path/to/custom/etc'
. "$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC/artemis.profile"
```

The first line sets the path used to find `artemis.profile`. The second line actually pulls the values from `artemis.profile` into the `artemis` script.

Comment: I add the env_var for etc path ...what is the second line ?

Comment: Justin..can you explain the second line  . "$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC/artemis.profile"

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: is there a more simple way to get the profile pointing to the custom jolokia-access

Comment: I'm not aware of a "more simple" way to change the profile.

Comment: Justin...i copied in the custom profile after creating broker ..seems cleaner

Comment: It is a pity you can pass in broker.xml & bootstrap.xml but not the artemis.profile - it was a big effort to get the web console working through Kubernetes Pod

Comment: can you consider this solution ? is it better to copy artemis.profile to broker/etc after broker instance is created ?

Comment: The fundamental answer is that there is, in fact, no *direct* support for using a custom `artemis.profile`. That is the real answer to the question you posed. I offered a potential work-around. You found another work-around that was better for your use-case. The answer is still viable regardless.